# Issue configuring Thunderbird on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, email, thunderbird, gmail

At the office, I have an email address that we can access from http://gmail.mycompany.com/. I would like to use Thunderbird instead of gmail's online interface.

When I started Thrunderbird for the first time, it tried to detect the proper configuration from my email address, but it did not work.

I copied the configuration from a colleague's PC:

```
IN
imap.googlemail.com port 993 SSL/TLS
myid@mycompany.com

OUT
smtp.googlemail.com port 465 SSL/TLS
myid@mycompany.com
```

Yet, it still does not work.

When I open Thunderbird, it asks me for a password for:

```
myid@mycompany.com@imap.googlemail.com
```

This does not seem right. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

1) Select Menu: Edit -> Account Settings
2) Select "Server Settings" for the IMAP account
3) Write correct IMAP login in "User Name" field

[Based on Debian installation]